# How to copy a lua function from one lua_State to another lua_State in c++

Tags: c++, lua

I run a small gameserver, I have one thread and one lua_State, the thread is always busy with small tasks but every now and then a heavier tasks is requested which causes a small hang of around 100-200ms, I know exactly what these tasks are and I've optimized them as much as possible.

Now I added a second thread and a second lua_State, when one of these heavy tasks is called from lua_State 'one', the tasks is passed to lua_State 'two' which is running on the second thread and is executed in the background so this doesn't lag the game itself.

I was starting the second lua_State with 'lua_newthread' and passing the values from one state to the other using 'lua_xmove', corrected problems I found on the way, etc.

I got the idea almost working correctly but then I started having crashes due memory corruption (not always), researching a bit I found that I need to implement lua_lock() and lua_unlock(), which is not really an option for me because it would affect the performance, I have thousands of lua calls per minute.

So I decided to change it a bit and start the second lua_State with 'luaL_newstate', right now I am stuck after hours researching and trying different methods, so I decided to ask for help here for the very first time.

**I am trying to copy/move data in the stack from one state to the other but I don't really know how to handle the lua defined functions.**

This is what I have right now

```
void moveValue(lua_State* from, lua_State* to)
{
    switch(lua_type(from, -1))
    {
        case LUA_TNIL:
        {
            lua_pushnil(to);
            break;
        }
        case LUA_TBOOLEAN:
        {
            lua_pushboolean(to, lua_toboolean(from, -1));
            break;
        }
        case LUA_TNUMBER:
        {
            lua_pushnumber(to, lua_tonumber(from, -1));
            break;
        }
        case LUA_TSTRING:
        {           
            size_t len;
            const char* str = lua_tolstring(from, -1, &len);

            lua_pushlstring(to, str, len);
            break;
        }
        case LUA_TFUNCTION:
        {
            break;
        }

        default:
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    lua_pop(from, 1); // Pop the value we just read
}
```

```
int32_t luaDoHeavyTask(lua_State* L)
{
    // doHeavyTask(...) 
    int32_t parameters = lua_gettop(L);
    if(!lua_isfunction(L, -parameters))
    {
        lua_pushboolean(L, false);
        return 1;
    }
    
    for(int32_t i = 0; i < parameters; i++)
    {
        moveValue(L, m_luaState_tmp);
    }
    
    // ...
    // ...
}
```

And the lua side looks like this

```
doHeavyTask(PLAYER_PROFILE.internal_send, send_to, name)

PLAYER_PROFILE.internal_send = function(send_to, name)
    -- do a lot of stuff
end
```

**I want to achieve this using the less external tools possible because it won't get more complex than this, using libraries or re writing the whole lua enviroment would be overkill.**

Also sorry for my awful english, it is not my first language.

Edit:

The function shares globals and upvalues with the rest of the code, I got it working at the moment with a workaround

I pass the function and parameters as a string to the second thread

```lua
PLAYER_PROFILE.send = function(send_to, name)
    doHeavyTask([[
        local send_to = ]] .. send_to .. [[
        local name = "]] .. name .. [["
        PLAYER_PROFILE.internal_send(send_to, name)
    ]])
end
```

and then do luaL_loadbuffer and lua_pcall from the second lua_State, it is working at the moment by using this method. But I am still interested into learning how to handle lua functions in c.

Comment: What upvalues, if any, will the functions that you'll be copying have?

Comment: Does your function share globals/upvalues with the rest of the code?

Comment: updated main post